# Security Analysis

Tags: block-cipher

I have designed my own lightweight cryptographic algorithm and now measuring its security. I was finding bounds on probabilities against linear and differential attacks. For differential characteristic I got probability of $\le 2^{-125}$ in 25 rounds. Block length is 64 bits and key lengths are 96 or 128 bits. Should I increase number of rounds or is this security bound enough?

Comment: Is the differential attack you used the best possible attack against the algorithm? If not, then even if you increase rounds, there may be one significantly more efficient.

Comment: Highly recommended readings: Bruce Schneier's [Memo to the Amateur Cipher Designer](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1015.html#cipherdesign) then his [Self-Study Course in Block Cipher Cryptanalysis](https://www.schneier.com/academic/archives/2000/01/self-study_course_in.html). Corollary as applied to the question: given some nondescript «lightweight cryptographic algorithm», we don't have a methodology for «measuring its security».

Answer (score 2):

It's debatable, as you may have found out from the comments.

Let's drive into it:

- you've seemed to have performed the analysis, of course a third party analysis would be preferable;
- unless you have mathematical proof, it is unclear if your differential crypt-analysis is optimal, it may not be;
- other attacks may be more efficient;
- the cost of the attack seems only have been shown in nr of operations, memory cost etc. may play a role as well;

Most importantly, making suggestions about if the number of rounds should increase should be based on arguments on how the cipher operates and what kind of attacks are possible on it (such an argument would be out of scope for this site though). There is always a lot of argument between cryptographers how many rounds should be performed. For instance, in the AES and SHA-3 competitions many entrants have had the number of rounds changed between the phases of the competition.

In principle the attack is not sufficient to put a large hole in the security argument. 125 out of 128 is worse than the best known attack on AES (which is 126.8 bits of security, if I'm not mistaken). However, some leniency could be put in the fact that this is supposed to be a lightweight cipher. Preferably the best attack would take more operations than brute forcing so that the full security potential is reached.